# how do I add text lables on QQ plot?

Tags: r, qq

I am making QQ plot via:

```
library(ggman)
qq(fdr2_sorted$FDR.q.val2, main = "RG_All", pch = 17, col=fdr1_sorted$group, cex = 1, las = 1)
```

data frames used look like this:

```
> head(fdr1_sorted)
                                       NAME             GS<br> follow link to MSigDB  GS DETAILS SIZE         ES       NES NOM p-val
1:                 GO_DNA_PACKAGING_COMPLEX                 GO_DNA_PACKAGING_COMPLEX Details ...   77  0.6757226  2.466745         0
2:                   GO_PROTEIN_DNA_COMPLEX                   GO_PROTEIN_DNA_COMPLEX Details ...  132  0.5958179  2.346520         0
3:         GO_RESPONSE_TO_TYPE_I_INTERFERON         GO_RESPONSE_TO_TYPE_I_INTERFERON Details ...   52 -0.7521569 -2.533148         0
4:          GO_RESPONSE_TO_INTERFERON_GAMMA          GO_RESPONSE_TO_INTERFERON_GAMMA Details ...  101 -0.6370415 -2.420473         0
5: GO_CELLULAR_RESPONSE_TO_INTERFERON_GAMMA GO_CELLULAR_RESPONSE_TO_INTERFERON_GAMMA Details ...   85 -0.6571892 -2.402153         0
 6:                 GO_GRANULOCYTE_MIGRATION                 GO_GRANULOCYTE_MIGRATION Details ...   43 -0.7332099 -2.398983         0
   FDR q-val FWER p-val RANK AT MAX                   LEADING EDGE V12 group FDR.q.val2
1:         0          0        1111 tags=43%, list=10%, signal=47%  NA     2      1e-10
2:         0          0        1516 tags=39%, list=13%, signal=45%  NA     2      1e-10
3:         0          0        1427 tags=54%, list=12%, signal=61%  NA     4      1e-10
4:         0          0        1819 tags=45%, list=16%, signal=52%  NA     4      1e-10
5:         0          0        1216 tags=38%, list=11%, signal=42%  NA     4      1e-10
6:         0          0         491  tags=28%, list=4%, signal=29%  NA     4      1e-10

> head(fdr2_sorted)
                                       NAME             GS<br> follow link to MSigDB  GS DETAILS SIZE         ES       NES NOM p-val
1:                 GO_DNA_PACKAGING_COMPLEX                 GO_DNA_PACKAGING_COMPLEX Details ...   77  0.6757226  2.466745         0
2:                   GO_PROTEIN_DNA_COMPLEX                   GO_PROTEIN_DNA_COMPLEX Details ...  132  0.5958179  2.346520         0
3:         GO_RESPONSE_TO_TYPE_I_INTERFERON         GO_RESPONSE_TO_TYPE_I_INTERFERON Details ...   52 -0.7521569 -2.533148         0
4:          GO_RESPONSE_TO_INTERFERON_GAMMA          GO_RESPONSE_TO_INTERFERON_GAMMA Details ...  101 -0.6370415 -2.420473         0
5: GO_CELLULAR_RESPONSE_TO_INTERFERON_GAMMA GO_CELLULAR_RESPONSE_TO_INTERFERON_GAMMA Details ...   85 -0.6571892 -2.402153         0
 6:                 GO_GRANULOCYTE_MIGRATION                 GO_GRANULOCYTE_MIGRATION Details ...   43 -0.7332099 -2.398983         0
FDR q-val FWER p-val RANK AT MAX                   LEADING EDGE V12 FDR.q.val2
1:         0          0        1111 tags=43%, list=10%, signal=47%  NA      1e-10
2:         0          0        1516 tags=39%, list=13%, signal=45%  NA      1e-10
3:         0          0        1427 tags=54%, list=12%, signal=61%  NA      1e-10
4:         0          0        1819 tags=45%, list=16%, signal=52%  NA      1e-10
5:         0          0        1216 tags=38%, list=11%, signal=42%  NA      1e-10
6:         0          0         491  tags=28%, list=4%, signal=29%  NA      1e-10
```

and I would like to get the plot like the one in attach, where there are text labels above the points that meet threshold. Also how would I add legend to this plot?

[image]